# Where to add a folder on a Pi sd card to put movies from my Mac?

Tags: raspbmc, media

So this seems like a obvious question but all I am finding answers to are streaming solutions. I want to play a movie from my Pi hooked up to my tv. I want to put the file from my mac to the pi's sd card so when it boots up it I can play the movie. On my Mac though it only comes up as three partitions (recovery, and 2 Boots for arch linux and raspmc) so i do not know where to put a movie folder. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are trying to create a folder on your sd card by accessing the image? If that is the case, I think you are going about it the wrong way. You should boot up your pi and create a folder on your pi. You can use CyberDuck to transfer the movie to your pi from your mac, or simply mount your mac share on your pi.

Comment: yea i figured something was wrong. I can only see the partition images on my mac but not the sd itself. theres no way to access the empty storage without going through the pi itself? I would like to know how to move files without going through the network if possible, thanks for the help

Comment: Why not ftp the file from your mac to the sdcard? http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/ftp-access/

Comment: Filezilla for mac will do it without issue http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/3.9.0.3/FileZilla_3.9.0.3_macosx-x86.app.tar.bz2/download?nowrap

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer files without going through a network, you can use a USB Memory Flash drive

You can find a nice tutorial [here](http://raspi.tv/2012/mount-a-usb-flash-drive-on-raspberry-pi). Since links can die, here is what the link says:

First we need to find out where our system locates the device. With the USB device not plugged in, type…

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Then plug in your USB device and, looking in the new lines which appear, make a note of the ID – it will be something like `sda1`, `sdb1`, `sda2`, `sdb2` etc.

[image: Tail]

finding the ID of USB device. Then CTRL-C to stop the tail command. In this case the usb stick id is `sda1`. That means the device is located in `/dev/sda1`.

Next, we need to create a directory under `/media`, so you will be able to mount your drive.

```
sudo mkdir /media/usbstick (usbstick can be whatever you want to call it)
```

Then we mount the usb stick with…

If you are logged in as root…

```
mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/sda1 /media/usbstick/
```

…where sda1 is its id from the tail command and usbstick is the directory you just made.

If you are logged in as the default Raspberry Pi debian user, pi, you will need to use…

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /media/usbstick/
```

…or you won’t get read/write access (the -o stands for options, uid is user id and gid is group id).

Then you can go there and have a look…

```
cd /media/usbstick
ls -l
```

result of `ls -l command`

[image: Listing]

…and you should get a listing of what’s on the USB stick you just mounted.

Comment: Lol haha links go to die here idk why but that's hilarious.   But thanks for your answer I guess I was hoping I could take out the SD and add files in my Mac then plug it back into the pie to read.  Do you think you could partition the SD (mines relatively big at 16gb) just for media so it could be written to by Mac.? Also is that something that needs to reformat the SD and do from the beggining? Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think so, but you can google. But the question is why would you?

Comment: Well I'm at a school that has a wifi system set up so to do it over the network, not that I have anything bad, I just don't like the idea of sending my stuff through the community router. And with the usb it is just one extra thing you need. I already have a computer with an sd slot so i figured I can just put my media and stuff on there in a folder on the sd (i was thinking a partition both can read but couldn't find anything) and then boot it from the pi to use on my tv.